# Apache Commons CLI: no exception thrown after passing illegal arguments to options

Tags: java, command-line-interface, apache-commons, apache-commons-cli

My problem is that I don't see an any exception thrown when an option that should accept no argument is given an argument.

Just standard setup, straight from the documentation

```
Options options = new Options();
CommandLineParser parser = new DefaultParser();
CommandLine cmd;
```

option:

```
Option op = Option.builder("op")
                  .longOpt("op")
                  .hasArg(false)
                  .desc("bla")
                  .build();
options.addOption(op);
```

try-catch:

```
try {
    cmd = parser.parse(options, args);
    if (cmd.hasOption("op") { //do something }
} catch (ParseException | IllegalArgumentException exp) {
    System.err.println(exp.getMessage());
    System.exit(0);
}
```

I've tried every method that seems relevant provided in the Option.Builder class([link](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/apidocs/org/apache/commons/cli/Option.Builder.html)), but none of them throws an exception at `-op` with an argument, say, `-op hello`

Is there an exception class that handles illegal arguments of options in Apache Commons CLI or do we have to manually do so? (then what's the point of having a method like hasArg(boolean hasArg)? )

Comment: I dont know if this is the answer, but you seem to have parsed your options when initialising cmd, and then again later in the try catch. I'd : CommandLine cmd = null.. then later try { cmd = parser.parse(.....) } See if that helps?

Comment: @FreudianSlip I did have an uninitialized cmd but then copied the wrong code here. Thanks for pointing out tho! I have reedited the question.

Comment: Does the argument (--op) have an argument value when you do --op hello ? or is the argument value just being ignored?

Comment: Try something like : options.addOption("t", false, "display current time"); .. taken from https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/usage.html .. the 'false' means no argument is expected for this parameter.

Comment: @FreudianSlip Yes, the argument value is ignored regardless of whether I pass an argument to `--op`. `cmd.getOptionValue(op)` always returns null. And to the second question: I tried, didn't work.

Comment: See the last answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36166630/apache-commons-cli-not-parsing-as-expected .. looks like you're encountering the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Commons CLI by supports "trailing arguments", i.e. `<options> arg1 [arg2...]`.

If you look at `getArgs()` or `getArgList()` you see that the option did not parse the value and so it ended up in the list of trailing arguments.

```
    Option op = Option.builder("op")
            .longOpt("op")
            .hasArg(false)
            .desc("bla")
            .build();

    Options options = new Options();
    options.addOption(op);

    CommandLineParser parser = new DefaultParser();
    CommandLine cmd = parser.parse(options, new String[] {"-op", "bla"});
    assertTrue(cmd.hasOption(op));

    assertEquals("[bla]", cmd.getArgList().toString());
    assertEquals("[bla]", Arrays.toString(cmd.getArgs()));
```

I did not find a way to disallow such trailing arguments.

So if you want to fail when this happens, you can check and throw an exception if getArgs() returns a non-empty array.

Comment: I will have other options as well and their illegal arguments would end up in the same list of trailing arguments that you mentioned. Then I can't make my error message precise :( I guess Commons CLI just sucks...

Comment: Don't underestimate commandline argument parsing. It's quite complex to get it "right" and commons-cli tries to give you a simple solution for simple use-cases...